# HTML в PHP или наоборот?

Tags: php, html

У меня происходит генерация странички сайта с помощью информации из базы данных. Изначально я создавал шаблон и пробные варианты фронт-энда и когда наконец дизайн готов пришло время к серверной составляющей. Тут у меня и вопрос.

Как правильнее будет сделать: переименовать index.html в index.php и делать в него вставки(include) нужных динамически генерируемых модулей или наоборот, то есть в index.php будут одни вставки модулей, в которых уже в перемешку будет идти и дизайн и генерация контента? Вопрос не только что лучше, но и почему?

Я никогда не понимал как стоит вести структуру веб-сайта и у меня постоянно были какие-то перемешивания стилей что доводило до того что я уже терялся в структуре проекта. Пришло время разобраться.

Comment: правильнее будет отделять мух от котлет. Отделяйте логику от представления. Используйте шаблоны (Smarty, Twig). В пхп-коде извлекайте и подготавливайте данные, передавайте их в tpl-шаблон (смарти), который полностью отвечает только за представление данных.

Comment: Работая с фреймворками мое понимание следующее - вы отправляете вопрос на сервер, сервер отдает вам ответ (данные). Соответственно должна быть страница в которую можно вставить эти данные (.php в вашем случае). А дальше вставляйте эти данные куда вам нужно. Например `<h1><?= $title ?></h1>` (из ответа серевера должна была придти строковая переменная $title)

Comment: @teran Я примерно так это и вижу у себя в голове. Но на деле я не совсем понимаю как это реализовать. Было бы круто если бы вы показали примеры(довольно простые, просто что бы показать логику).

Comment: @Oleg Shleif Я работаю без фреймворков в этом проекте, мой собственный чистый код. Вся страница генерируется на сервере, и когда она будет сгенерирована сервер отправит ее юзеру. Потому вопрос именно в том как выглядит структура главного файла генерации этой страницы на сервере.

Comment: @Telion простейший пример использования smarty можно найти в [описании метки `Smarty`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/smarty/info)

Comment: @teran Это на самом деле выглядит довольно удобно. Я полагаю точно так же можно и на чистом PHP интегрировать дынне в шаблон.

Comment: а смысл изобретать велосипед, когда есть готовые решения проверенные временем и разработанные исходя из нужд тех кто их использует? Ваш самодельный шаблон будет более громоздким и менее гибким.

Comment: @Telion почитайте про простейшую реализацию MVC, попробуйте её реализовать и использовать. Или перепишите всё на любом популярном фреймворке.

Comment: @Oboroten Да, я уже понял о чем говорил teran, просто единственное где я имел дело с MVC до сих пор это angularJS и я все еще на стартовых этапах его изучения. Тем не менее я не верю что это единственный вариант формирования шаблона сайта, явно ведь используются другие варианты, нет?

Comment: В php yii, laravel, magento основаны на mvc. Скорее всего и большинство прочих фреймворков. По сути это мнение сообщества, что mvc идеально подходит для php. А в js полная реализация mvc нигде не используется.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте. Очень советовал бы Вам ознакомиться с таким паттерном проектирования, как MVC:
http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=666
Именно на нем построено большинство современных фреймворков. Если Вы разберетесь с ним, то создавать сайты Вам станет гораздо легче да и освоить любой фреймворк будет гораздо проще.
Если дружите с английским, то вот ссылка на иностранный иточник:

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Прикольный ID поста, но, на жаль, я не могу попасть на сайт...

Comment: Не обязательно именно эта статья. Их много. Главное желание искать.